# Java recursion to find prime factors doesn't work

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to get all prime factors of a number. The `for` loop should work until it finds the match and it should break and jump to the next `if` statement which checks if number is not equal to zero.

```
public class Factor {

    public static ArrayList <Integer> HoldNum = new ArrayList(); 

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Factor object = new Factor();
        object.Factor(104);
        System.out.println(HoldNum.get(0));
    }

    public static int Factor(int number){
        int new_numb = 0;
        int n=0;
        for( n = 1; n < 9; n++) {                 
            if (number % n == 0) {
                HoldNum.add(n);
                new_numb = number/n;
                break;           
            }
        }

        System.out.println(new_numb);
        if(new_numb < 0) {
            HoldNum.add(new_numb);
            return 1;
        } else {
            return Factor(new_numb);
        }                   

    }
}
```

Comment: You have not stated the problem that you are currently facing.

Comment: You need to tell us what happens? (And quite often _explaining_ the problem to someone else leads you to the solution yourself.)

Comment: Your for-loop mutable variable is nowhere incremented.

Comment: the problem is that it will create an infinitive loop

Comment: My logic is that that the forloop will work until it finds a suitable value which can be divided evenly with int number and then the suitable value would be stored in Arraylist Holdnum. THe break statement should stop the for loop if the suitable value is find, after that the program should check if the remainin value is less than 0 and if not, should return the Factor with new value

Comment: @m2rt Without digging too deep, I'd say that a reasonable for-loop would have a lower bound of 1 (or 2) and upper bound equal to the _current_ integer you are trying to divide... see Harmlezz's answer for instance.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three errors :

- As okiharaherbst wrote, your counter is not incremented.
- you start your loop at 1, so yourval % 1 always equals to 0 and new_numb is always equals to your input val, so you'll loop endlessly on 104.
- new_numb will never be lesser than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a recursive solution. Here you go:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factors(104));
    }

    public static List<Integer> factors(int number) {
        return factors(number, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

    private static List<Integer> factors(int number, List<Integer> primes) {
        for (int prim = 2; prim <= number; prim++) {
            if (number % prim == 0) {
                primes.add(prim);
                return factors(number / prim, primes);
            }
        }
        return primes;
    }
}
```

The code is not bullet-proof, it is only a quick-and-dirty example.

Answer (score 0):

Java implementation...

```
public class PrimeFactor {

public int divisor=2;
void printPrimeFactors(int num)
{

    if(num == 1)
        return;

    if(num%divisor!=0)
        {
        while(num%divisor!=0)
            ++divisor;          
        }
    if(num%divisor==0){

    System.out.println(divisor);
        printPrimeFactors(num/divisor);
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PrimeFactor obj = new PrimeFactor();
    obj.printPrimeFactors(90);
}

}
```